# Google Sheets Tally per week

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I need a list of all unique participants for each week starting every Sunday, where the Type is not TypeD

So given the source image, it should only look at Data from Sunday to Saturday, then look at the List of Unique Participants and tally their weekly participation.

Now i have started with this

```
=QUERY({C:C,C:C},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1)
```

but it doesn't separate the comma delimitation or look at a table of ALL participants because if you notice; participant F should be 0 since they didn't contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say A is the column with dates, C with participants. You also put weeks in column F and participants to be looked up at G. Then the following, entered in H2, will count the number of times the participant named in G2 was present during the week of F2:

```
=countifs(A:A, ">=" & F2, A:A, "<" & (F2+7), C:C, "*" & G2 & "*")
```

The formula can be dragged down the H column to count the rest.

Explanation of the conditions imposed here:

- entry in A is at least F2 but less than F2+7
- entry in C *contains* the string in G2. The asterisks in `"*" & G2 & "*"` are wildcards matching any number of any characters.

Comment: Thanks that works really well, one last question, is there a way for me to specifically say i only want to go from Sunday 8:00PM to Sunday 7:59 or would that formula above work in that case as well?

Comment: You want to add 20 hours to the cutoff date. Replace `F2` by `F2 + 20/24` to this effect. And `(F2+7)` would be `(F2+7+20/24)`